# Manage external custom permissions with WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to add custom permission and role to IS .Use case available in here http://venurakahawala.blogspot.in/search/label/custom%20permissions .How to implement this scenario .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WSO2IS 5.0.0 to achieve this.

1. Create a service provider which represent your application
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider
2. Define custom permission for service provider
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions+for+a+Service+Provider
3. Can create new roles and assign permissions for each roles 
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Roles